# Can't validate windows xp after a clean install

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp

I purchased an upgrade disk of windows 7.

Before upgrading I bought a new hdd and reinstalled xp. I have a genuine copy of xp. After trying to validate xp over the phone I was informed that the copy may be a fake and go to www.mi..com/genuine where the page states xp is no longer sold and click to buy windows7. I have reinstalled xp several times to clean installs but I've never had a problem before.

I've tried installing microsoft diagnostics but it sends me back to a help page, where it tells me how to validate xp by phone or over the internet, loop.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially what's happened is hardware has changed in your PC - each time a Windows install takes place your hardware is audited (for all intents and purposes) and mapped to your license key. Any change in H/W and frequent reinstalls (several times as quoted above) and for all MS knows you are installing this one copy of XP on multiple machines.

Just use the freephone number provided and activate over the phone - if the automated service says your copy is not genunine, hold the line, and you will be transferred through to a rep who will merely ask you, "How many PC's is it installed on" and active it there and then.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. The problem is that the message on the phone activation number says that the copy may be a fake and to go to the website which tells me to buy winddows7.

Comment: Sorry - please see my edit. Pressing # on the phone iirc transfers you through.

Comment: And If you have a copy of the Windows 7 disc, whether or not its an Upgrade disc you can install that - to get around the licensing issue, just do a custom install via booting from the CD, then, do an upgrade install within Windows 7, to Windows 7 again, so that you can use your 'Upgrade' license.

Comment: If this advice has been of any use, please rate my post and mark answered if it has solved your problem :)

Comment: Its not "any" change in hardware, it usually takes multiple changes in smaller hardware or a motherboard change to trigger the key to be un-activateable. If it is a retail licence, it can be transferred to any hardware, but could require phone activation, OEM or "system builder" copies of Windows are tied to the hardware they were originally installed on for Life. TheD never stated what type of installed CD they used. If your Retail key gets released for some unknown reason and used by others, it can get blacklisted by Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste this below code with notepad

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion]
"CurrentBuild"="1.511.1 () (Obsolete data - do not use)"
"ProductId"="55274-640-7450093-23464"
"DigitalProductId"=hex:a4,00,00,00,03,00,00,00,35, 35,32,37,34,2d,36,34,30,2d,\
37,34,35,30,30,39,33,2d,32,33,34,36,34,00,2e,00,00 ,00,41,32,32,2d,30,30,30,\
30,31,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,62,fc,61,4c,e0,26,33,16 ,05,d3,54,e7,a0,de,00,00,\
00,00,00,00,49,36,c2,49,20,47,0c,00,00,00,00,00,00 ,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,33,33,35,30,30,00 ,00,00,00,00,00,00,65,10,\
00,00,74,99,dd,b0,f7,07,00,00,98,10,00,00,00,00,00 ,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00 ,c4,ae,d6,1c
"LicenseInfo"=hex:e7,77,18,19,f8,08,fc,7d,e8,f0,df ,12,6e,46,cb,3f,ad,b2,dd,b9,\
15,18,16,c0,bc,c3,6a,7d,4a,80,8b,31,13,37,5a,78,a2 ,06,c8,6b,b9,d9,dd,cc,6a,\
9c,c5,9b,77,aa,07,8d,56,6a,7c,e4

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WPAEvents]
"OOBETimer"=hex:ff,d5,71,d6,8b,6a,8d,6f,d5,33,93,f d
```

- Save that document. As "file type" choose "all files" and give it a name that is up to you. 
  You have to use the extestion ".reg". ex "Ori.reg".
- After it's saved, double click the file from Explorer.
- If a question dialog appears ("Are you sure?"), click  "Yes".

In order to make sure that it worked, open this page. Look on the right side, then click on "Validate Windows", then install.